# $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty I_i $ not superset of $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Index all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ from 1 to infinity. For each rational number $q$ in $[0,1]$, form a set $I_i=[q-\frac\epsilon{2^i},q+\frac\epsilon{2^i}]$, where $\epsilon$ is a small number, maybe $\epsilon=0.01$. Now consider the set $$A=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty I_i $$ Set $A$ seems to be a superset of $[0,1]$ because for any number $x\in[0,1]$, there is a rational number that is very close to it. So $x\in I_i$ for some $i$. But the measure of $A$ is $\epsilon$ and the measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$. Does this mean there must be numbers in $[0,1]$ but not $A$? If so, what are those numbers or how to construct them? Also why is the argument for $x\in I_i$ for some $i$ incorrect?

Comment: *Remark*. No one ever uses the term "superset", you should have used $[0,1]$ contained in ...

Comment: @313 that is not true.

Comment: @AAA: of course some people use it, but it is not standard terminology. I have never seen an authoritative source using it.

Comment: @313 yes it is. I'm not sure what you mean by "authoritative source" but the term was used fluently throughout all of my undergraduate career. Plus, I'm not sure what else you would call a set that contains all the elements and possibly more of a given set.

Comment: @OohAah: I know. But writing "superset" (the word itself) is not standard.

Comment: @313 : If you're fastidious, you might say "included in" rather than "contained in".  If $x\in X$ then $x$ is contained in $X$, but if $x\subseteq X$, then $x$ is included in $X$.  After all, one says "partially ordered by inclusion", but never "partially ordered by containment". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Actually @313, the term "superset" is used reasonably often in logic; e.g. http://indigo.uic.edu/handle/10027/10461 by John Baldwin, http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/mildenberger/postings/paperspdf/bs242_2014_05_26.pdf by Blass/Shelah/Mildenberger, and people.maths.ox.ac.uk/zilber/cat.ps by Boris Zilber, in addition to the paper OohAah mentions. Regardless of how you rate the individual papers (and what exactly is your background to judge the quality of logic papers?), these are all serious researchers. It may not be very common, but it's certainly non-cranky.

Comment: Also page 1298 of the Handbook of Algebraic Topology: https://books.google.com/books?id=xoM5DxQZihQC&pg=PA1298&lpg=PA1298&dq=superset+cohomology&source=bl&ots=pyFaiPLmvf&sig=_Yo_5HfB_Xa37oBuFvrR8R7D1h4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ThujVPX0OIb4yQTFgYGoAw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=superset%20cohomology&f=false, if you don't like logic. Tl;dr, I take issue with your statement "no one ever uses the term 'superset,'" as well as your later statement that using it makes one look 'cranky.' Please don't be so quick to disparage reasonable language, and people who use it, even if you don't.

Comment: (If nothing else, the term can be good for sentence structure: compare ". . . which is closed under supersets" with ". . . such that for any $A\subseteq B$, if $A\in\mathcal{F}$ then $B\in\mathcal{F}$." The fragment ". . . which is closed upwards under inclusion" is less clunky, but still feels a bit weird. Certainly we should all support making mathematical sentences less Byzantine in structure - the meaning is already complicated enough! :P)

Comment: @313: There seem to be a fair number of respectable hits in these google scholar searches: [superset+Lebesgue](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=superset+Lebesgue) and [superset + "metric space"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=superset+%22metric+space%22) and [superset + "Baire category"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=superset+%22Baire+category%22), and even one hit for [superset + "DL Renfro"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=superset+%22DL+Renfro%22).

Answer (score 3):

The argument for $x\in I_i$ is incorrect because you didn't specify "how very close" $x$ is to the rationals. There are (lots of) irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ that are not inside any $I_i$. For example, it is reasonably easy to see that you can manage to choose your indexing of the rationals in such a way that $\sqrt{2}/2$ is never inside any of the $I_i$. It just happens that this must be the case for an uncountably large number of irrationals, not only $\sqrt{2}/2$.

The way to construct these irrationals depends on your particular manner of enumerating the rationals. I said above that "it's easy to see that" you can enumerate the rationals in such a way that $\sqrt{2}/2$ is never inside any $I_i$. Well, it is indeed easy. Start with any enumeration $r_i$ of your choice. If the distance from $r_1$ to $\sqrt{2}/2$ is greater than $\epsilon/2^1$, take $q_1=r_1$. Otherwise, try the next $r_i$ until you reach an $r_i$ that is outside the interval $\left[\sqrt{2}/2-\epsilon/2^1,\sqrt{2}/2+\epsilon/2^1\right]$ (you eventually will). Now that you have set $q_1=r_i$, remove this $r_i$ from your original enumeration, and repeat the same algorithm to choose $q_2=r_j$ such that $q_2$ is outside the interval $\left[\sqrt{2}/2-\epsilon/2^2,\sqrt{2}/2+\epsilon/2^2\right]$. This way, you will end up choosing all of the $q_n$, and $\sqrt{2}/2$ will never be inside any of the $I_i$.

Also, note that the measure of $A$ is *less* than $\epsilon$, not equal to.

Answer (score 2):

There are irrational numbers which are in none of the $I_i$. For convenience let me replace your $\varepsilon$ by $\delta$, and I will list the rationals in $[0,1]$ as $\{ q_i \}_{i=1}^\infty$.

You do have that for every irrational $x$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a rational $q$ with $|x-q|<\varepsilon$. What you would need is not quantified the same way. You would need that some rational $q_i$ satisfies $|x-q_i|<\delta 2^{-i}$. That is, when we pick a rational we are immediately given the radius around it.

So it could happen that when you pick $\varepsilon$, all of the $q_i$ within $\varepsilon$ of $x$ have such large $i$ that $\delta 2^{-i}<\varepsilon$. Indeed notice that only finitely many $i$ satisfy $\delta 2^{-i} < \varepsilon$. So we can keep $x$ out of the union in an iterative fashion. Specifically we can get a sequence $\varepsilon_k$ going to zero and an increasing sequence $N_k$ so that for each $k$ and each $i=N_{k-1},N_{k-1}+1,\dots,N_k-1$, $|x-q_i|>\varepsilon_k$ with $N_k$ chosen sufficiently large for each $k$.

Being any more concrete will become counterproductive, I think. Part of the problem is that concrete examples require you to concretely specify an enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: It also tends to be hard to concretely specify very irrational numbers. The OP supplied a pretty good proof that some irrationals are missing by measuring all of them, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume your construction is as follows:

> Enumerate the rationals as $(q_n:n\in\mathbb N)$ (you didn't specify this).  Fix some small $\varepsilon>0$, and let $I_i=[q_i-2^{-i}\varepsilon,q_i+2^{-i}\varepsilon]$.  Then form
>   $$
> A=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} I_i
> $$

You claim that $A$ contains $[0,1]$ as a subset.  The reasoning is:

> For any real number $x\in[0,1]$, and for any $\delta>0$ there exists some rational $q\in[0,1]$ such that $|x-q|<\delta$.  We deduce that $x\in I_n$ for some $n$.

Unfortunately, that deduction is false.  The reason that it doesn't work is that although we can find some $q_n$ arbitrarily close to any $x\in[0,1]$, $n$ could be arbitrarily large itself, so the two endpoints $q_n-2^{-n}\varepsilon$ and $q_n+2^{-n}\varepsilon$ of $I_n$ could be *even closer* to $x$ than $q_n$.  I.e., $x\not\in I_n$.

I'd give you an example of some $x$ that's not contained in any of the $I_i$, but it depends on the enumeration $(q_n)$ that you fix to start with.  Besides, you yourself have provided a perfectly good proof that such an $x$ exists - the set $A$ has measure $\varepsilon$, so can't contain the whole of $[0,1]$!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to "somewhat constructively" produce a number not in the union of the intervals $I_i$.  Actually, for convenience let me modify the construction slightly so that $I_i$ has length $10^{-i}$ instead of $2\epsilon/2^i$.  Start with
the interval $J_0 = [0,1] = [a_0, a_0 + 1]$.  $I_1$ has length $1/10$, so it can't intersect more than one of $[0,0.1]$ and $[0.9, 1]$.  Choose $J_1 = [a_1, a_1 + 0.1]$ to be $[0,0.1]$ if that doesn't intersect $I_1$, otherwise $[0.9, 1]$.
Again, the length of $I_2$ is $1/10$ the length of $J_1$, and we can choose 
$J_2$ to be either the leftmost $1/10$ of $J_1$ (if that doesn't intersect $I_2$) or the rightmost $1/10$ of $J_1$ if it does.  Proceed inductively: $J_n = [a_n, a_n + 10^{-n}]$ will be an interval of length $10^{-n}$ that doesn't intersect $I_1, \ldots, I_n$.
Now let $x$ be the limit of $a_n$ as $n \to \infty$: in fact $x$ will have a decimal expansion whose first $n$ digits after the decimal point are the same as those of $a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

The answers given have pointed out the flaw in the OP's argument. Let me say a bit, though, about the *intuitive* content of the mistake.

The statement "if $x$ is arbitrarily close to elements of $A$ (or more precisely, if $\forall\epsilon>0\exists a\in A(d(x, a)<\epsilon)$), then $x\in A$" is just saying "$A$ is closed."

Of course not every set is closed. For example, consider $A=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. Of course 0 is arbitrarily close to elements of $A$, but not in $A$.

The intuitive response to this is often, "Sure, but we can make $A$ closed by just adding one point; that won't effect the size of $A$." This is true. However, this is often then extended to,

> We can always make $A$ closed just by adding "a bunch of single points," so that shouldn't change the size of $A$.

This is the part that is wrong, and often surprising for those seeing analysis for the first time! The closure of a set can be **vastly** larger than the original set, in essentially any sense of "largeness" whatsoever.

---

A dual mistake is assuming that all open dense sets are big; in fact, you can make countably many open dense sets whose intersection has measure 0!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple proof that no possible $\{I_i\}$ as specified by you will cover, based on counting integer points, using only the compactness of $[0,1]$ (once you know some measure theory, more general techniques supersede this, but I like the intuition this simple proof provides):

*Definition:* The *length* of an interval $I = [a,b]$ (with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b > a$) is $\mathrm{len}(I) = b-a$.

*Proposition:* Suppose $\{I_i\}_{i\in A}$ is a collection of open intervals and $\sum_{i\in A} \mathrm{len}(I_i) < 1$. Then $\cup_i I_i \not\supset [0,1]$.

*Proof:* Given $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda > 0$, let $\lambda[a,b] = [\lambda a, \lambda b]$.

Let the number of integer points contained in any set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be denoted $n(S)$. Then we have $b-a-1 \leq n(I) \leq b-a+1$ for $I = [a,b]$.

Now, if we assume by way of contradiction that $\{I_i\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$ then there exists a finite subcover. So we may assume without loss of generality that the index set $A$ is finite, say $A = \{1, \ldots, m\}$.

Let $\sum_{i=1}^m \mathrm{len}(I_i) = c < 1$.

Then $n(\cup_{i= 1}^m \lambda I_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^m (\lambda b_i - \lambda a_i + 1) = m + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^m \mathrm{len}(I_i) = m + \lambda c$.

Choose $\lambda > \frac{m}{1-c}$. Then $n(\lambda\cup_{i= 1}^m I_i) \leq m+\lambda c < \lambda = n(\lambda [0,1])$.

Thus $\lambda \cup_{i=1}^m I_i \not\supset \lambda[0,1]$.

Thus $\cup_{i=1}^m I_i \not\supset [0,1]$

$\square$

In your case, note that $\sum \mathrm{len}(I_i) = \epsilon = .001 < 1$.

Comment: Given a little prior background in measure theory, this seems a bit laborious. Provided you've proven it already, you can just use excision: $m \left ( [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i \right ) = 1 - m \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i \right ) \geq 1-\varepsilon>0$. So it is nonempty since $m(\emptyset)=0$. I think the OP understood this but had an intuitive problem with its consequences.

Comment: @Ian The point was to have this be an elementary proof, using only compactness of the interval. I agree that once you've covered any degree of measure theory, this proof is obsolete. While there are some mild calculations to make, I think this is a nice and intuitive proof, giving easy bounds for counts of integer points in large dilations of your sets.